# Issue with average calculated station spacing for objective analysis procedure

Tags: python, unidata, metpy

I am running the Barnes objective analysis procedure on Oklahoma Mesonet data using interpolate_to_grid, which reads in the calculated station spacing output from interpolate_to_points. This is calculated using ave_spacing = cdist(points, points).mean(), which appears to calculate the mean distance between each individual data point and *all* data points. As a result, I am getting an average station spacing of ~228 km when the actual average spacing between adjacent sites is 30-40 km. I'd like to be able to alter this value in the objective analysis procedure without having to sift through all the different dependencies to do so.

```
spacing = cdist(list(zip(xloc, yloc)), list(zip(xloc, yloc)))
print(spacing)

Output:
[[     0.         245145.42398369 281067.71959647 ... 181889.14491027
  307129.27783772 193503.08897866]
 [245145.42398369      0.         242581.9939922  ... 426945.42853957
  204288.62028541 345728.95107532]
 [281067.71959647 242581.9939922       0.         ... 410049.17526377
   70655.02912353 212376.09473731]
 ...
 [181889.14491027 426945.42853957 410049.17526377 ...      0.
  455951.64830299 226710.02224577]
 [307129.27783772 204288.62028541  70655.02912353 ... 455951.64830299
       0.         275129.18406574]
 [193503.08897866 345728.95107532 212376.09473731 ... 226710.02224577
  275129.18406574      0.        ]]


avg_spacing = np.mean(cdist(list(zip(xloc, yloc)), list(zip(xloc, yloc))))
print(avg_spacing)

Output:
227725.7196359123
```

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely a bug in MetPy that we'll need to address in an upcoming release. I've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1230).